# Where are HDFS directories created in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hdfs, hadoop2

I am running a simple, get-my-feet-wet, map reduce job, in pseudo-distributed mode as so:

```
bin/hadoop jar tm.jar TestMap input output
```

It ran fine the first time but on the second run, I am getting the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/tom/output already exists
```

The initial commands that created the HDFS directories, use a hadoop command:

```
 $ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
 $ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>
```

**A few questions:**

- Where are these HDFS directories created and can they be deleted, if already exsist?
- What's best practice for avoiding this?

Comment: `hadoop fs -ls /user/tom/output` or `hdfs dfs -ls  /user/tom/output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a MR job, it will expect the `ouput` directory to be non-existent.

The first run of the job created it and the re-attempt of the job with same output path caused this exception.

And from your post, the `output` directory is provided as a relative path, in such case the directory will be created inside the user's HDFS directory (`/user/username/output`).

Yes, you can delete them if they already exist and you do not need them anymore.

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R output
```

To avoid this, You can either delete the directory and submit your job or provide a different non-existent path as output for the job.

**Note:** For example, if the provided output path is `new/mapreduce/output`, Hadoop expects the parent `new/mapreduce/` to exist.

Comment: Thanks,  (+1) for the clear explanation @franklinsijo

Comment: Glad that it helped.